# I am interested in using toggle class to change the color of the background of an image

Tags: javascript, toggleclass

I set up a button to change the color.  It is showing `classA` but it will not change to `classB` `onclick`.  The button seems to be working so I am not sure what is not working here.  I would appreciate any help.  Here is the code.

```
'<script>
    function toggleclass() {
var myElement = document.getElementById("id1");
if(myElement.className == "classA") {
    myElement.className = "classB";
} else {
    myElement.className="classA";
}
   }
  window.onload=function() {
document.getElementById("btn1").onclick =toggleClass;
   }
     </script>'

 HTML

'<td><div id="id1" class="classA"><img src="images/this.png" width="300" height="300"   


alt="ttemp"></div>

 <input type="button" id="btn1" value="ChangeColor" />   

            </td>'

 CSS

'.classA {
width: 300px;
border: 2px solid black;
background-color: green;
color: red;
padding: 3px;
  }
  .classB {
width: 300px;
border: 2px solid black;
background-color: blue;
color: red;
padding: 3px;
  }'
```

Thanks for your help,

Frank

Answer (score 0):

Bro, do you even jQuery? http://api.jquery.com/click/

```
$('#btn1').click(function(){
    $('#id1').toggleClass('classB');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would do the following:

```
$('#btn1').on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#id1').toggleClass("classB");
});
```

The prevent code should stop the page from jumping but still preform the action whilst toggling the class

Just my 2 cents